# After deployment of Laravel code from local server to live server admin subfolder dashboard not redirecting

Tags: php, laravel-5, server

I uploaded my Laravel website from the demo server to the live server which is in shared hosting. Previously in my demo server when I try to access the admin dashboard it was working but when I tried to access it isn't redirecting to the admin dashboard.

Live URL :- https://oyeadventure.com/
Admin dashboard :- https://oyeadventure.com/admin

Any suggestions or help? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this link https://XXXXXX.com working properly?

Comment: check your `routes` group and after your `.htaccess`

Comment: Actual domain is http://oyeadventure.com/ and for admin http://oyeadventure.com/admin